# Routing not working in angular web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to route to a reset page from the login page of the webapp i'm working on but nothing happens when I click on "forgot Password".  when I replace #/login with #/reset in the address bar the view changes to the reset page so I know the route is setup correctly.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

My code:

in my login template:

`<a href="#" class="forgotPassword" ng-click="forgotPassword()">Forgot Password?`

In my login controller:

```
$scope.forgotPassword = function(){
    $location.path('/reset');
            }
```

Comment: Get rid of the blank `href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever using anchor tag and want to redirect by using ng-click, do not use `href`

for you remove the `href`

now your template look like this..

`<a class="forgotPassword" ng-click="forgotPassword()">Forgot Password?`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to redirect your view with the "href" tag instead of the "ng-click" function?

```
<a href="/reset" class="forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a>
```